# Java PC application - exported JAR do not behave as in development

Tags: java, netbeans

I have an classic Java application for PC. The result of the build is a JAR file which is running on Windows machine.

The application is reading some XML files and creating an HTML document as an end result. The Xml file contains specific language characters that are not native to English.

While in development, in the IDE (Apache NetBeans 13), build - > Run the exported HTML file **contains** specific language characters.

When I run the JAR file, from the Project - > dist directory , HTML **do not** contain specific language characters.

For example characters like: č , ć , đ, š are being exported as : Ä�  , while running from NetBeans they are exported as such, not as that strange symbol.
The letters in question are from Serbian, Croatian and Bosnian.

When I export the project from NetBeans, I made sure to have this option enabled:
Project -> Project properties -> Build -> Packaging where the "Copy Dependent Libraries" option is selected.

I am puzzled at this point. If anybody has any idea why something is working one way in IDE and other when exported please let me know.

Comment: You need to get much more specific about the problem

Comment: @g00se I believe it is explained in details. Please let me know which part you think is problematic ?

Comment: So for example, you'd like us to *guess* which "specific language characters" are a problem?

Comment: @g00se Updated that info in the question. Thank you.

Comment: Well you probably need to set the characters encodings properly, in the output. Probably in the input too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likely problem is that your HTML file needs to identify its [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding). Nowadays, generally best to use [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) as the encoding for most purposes.

## Determine the file’s encoding

If you have access to the source code of your Java app, examine that to see what character encoding is being used when producing the HTML file. But I assume you have no such access.

Open the HTML file in a [text-editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_editor) to examine its raw source code. See if it specifies a character encoding. If it does, and that character encoding indicator is incorrect, you will need to alter your HTML file.

If no character encoding is indicated within the HTML, you will need to experiment to discover the encoding. Open the HTML file in a web browser, then use the "view" or developer tools available in most browsers (Firefox, Safari, Edge, etc.) to explicitly switch between encodings.

[image: screenshot of Safari text-encoding menu]

If switching to a particular encoding causes the text to appear as expected, then you know the likely encoding.

## Specify the file’s encoding

In the modern version of HTML, [HTML5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5), [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is the default encoding assumed by the web browser. But if the web browser switches into [Quirks Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode), the browser may assume another encoding. To help avoid Quirks Mode, a HTML5 document should start with `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

So, **best to be explicit about the encoding**. Once you determine the encoding being used by your Java app creating the HTML file, either alter that app (if you have source code) to write an indicator of the encoding, or else write another Java app to edit the produced HTML file to include the indicator. If you are not a Java developer, you could use any programming language or even a shell script to edit the produced HTML file.

To indicate the encoding of an HTML5 file, add a [`meta` element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_element).

For UTF-8:

```xml
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

For [Latin-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1):

```xml
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
```

If your Java app was developed exclusively on Microsoft Windows, the developer may have knowingly or unwittingly used one of the Microsoft defined character encodings. Older versions of Java defaulted to using a character encoding specific to the host platform — but be aware in Java 18+ the [default changes to UTF-8](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/400) across platforms.

## For more info

You can read about these issues in *many* places. Like [here](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_utf8.asp) and [in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML).

If you are not savvy with character sets and character encoding, I highly recommend reading the surprisingly entertaining article, [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/), by Joel Spolsky.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I have checked the reference you mentioned and the UTF encoding of the HTML file, I added the the encoding you mentioned and it changed the strange symbols from one type to other strange symbols. I will try to play with encodings and update. What also puzzles me that the file that works and this one are identical :(

Comment: The information from Basil is all good, but specifying the character encoding in the html output alone won't help you if what you specify does not represent the *actual* encoding of the file (which I suspect it doesn't)

Comment: @AdrianIvasku "play with encodings" — exactly. If you do not have access to the source code to see what character encoding is being used, then you will just have to experiment, trial-and-error, to determine an encoding that is likely being used. But as I said, if the app is relying on the host platform's default encoding, then redeploying your app to another platform will change the encoding, and moving to Java 18 will change to UTF-8.

Comment: The [Comment by g00se](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71551007/java-pc-application-exported-jar-do-not-behave-as-in-development/71551158#comment126460027_71551158) is important: Look at the source code of the generated HTML file to see if it specifies a `charset`. If so, and it is wrong, you will need to alter that part of the generated HTML file.

Comment: If you post a link to the html file with the problematic chars, we can take a look

Comment: @g00se sure. Here is the HTML exported from NetBeans (https://codeshare.io/YLRBQm) and the file exported when running the JAR file (https://codeshare.io/OdzAjN) It is crazy because both files do not contain encoding info and are identical. One works, other not.

Comment: Windows-1250 could well be the actual encoding

Comment: Thank you both for detailed explanation and time. I think I fixes it by adding the UTF encoding to the XML file I am using as a source to get the HTML file. Although the encoding is not included in the HTML file, it somehow works. I will set this as an aswer.

Comment: Changing to Windows-1250 makes your html work, but what you should do is write it out in your app properly encoded as UTF-8